# Проблема кодировки на Apache на Windows2012

Tags: php, ajax, кодировка

Сломал голову, помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.
У меня есть небольшой скрипт, который выполняет php exec команду с каталогами на сетевом ресурсе.
Структура проекта:

```
.htaccess
Controller.php
Config.php
FolderReader.class.php
public/ index.php
        script.js
```

Простой пример: 
На пользовательской странице `index.php` c заголовком

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

в директории public через js я получаю значение в input и отправляю в php-файл контроллер post запрос по Ajax

В Ajax дополнительно указываю параметр `scriptCharset: "utf-8"`;
(Пробовал и без указания, но разницы никакой), отправляется к примеру переменная `number=1234;`

В файле контроллера принимаю:

```
if (isset($_POST['number']) && !empty($_POST['number'])){
    $project =  $_POST['number'];

    //создается объект и выполняется его метод
    $finder = new FolderReader($project);
    $data = $finder->permissionSetter();
    //данные возвращаются на страницу
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Есть несколько промежуточных методов которые выполняют валидацию, перед созданием объекта, но это сейчас не важно.

Что делает метод permissionSetter():
Он считывает каталог, и выполняет exec команду на всех дочерних папках.
Если выполнять ее в терминале windows - выглядит она так

`icacls "\\10.0.7.41\project\1111_Project\1111_01_Каталог" /inheritance:e /T` или

`icacls "\\10.0.7.41\project\1111_Project\1111_02_Каталог" /inheritance:e /T` или

```
icacls "\\10.0.7.41\project\1111_Project\1111_03_AnyFolder" /inheritance:e /T
```

Где в цифры 1111 в \1111_Project\ это number из post.(как в промежутке получается полный путь думаю тоже не важно). 
В методе permissionSetter я перебираю массив с папками и для каждой папки выполняю exec.
Полный код метода :

```
public function permissionSetter()
    {
        if (!empty($this->foldersForRewting)){
            $paths = $this->foldersForRewting;
            foreach ($paths as $path){
                $command = 'icacls ' . ' "' . $path . '"" ' . '/inheritance:e /T';
                $this->data['messages']['execCommand'][] = $command;
                if (exec($command,$this->data['messages']['execSystem'][]))
                {
                    $this->data['messages']['execSuccess'][] = 'Разрешения на каталог: '. $path .' установлены';
                } else {
                    $this->data['messages']['execFail'][] = 'Ошибка установки разрешений: '. $path;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->data['messages']['errors'] = 'You try call setting permission on empty array';
        }
        return $this->data;
    }
```

Результат выполнения метода записываю в результирющуу переменную $data(ассоциативный массив с логами происходящего) в контроллере и отдаю обратно через `echo json_encode($data);`  в Ajax 
Что я получаю в консоли, если использую Ajax:
[image]

Моя exec команда отрабатывает, но только с каталогами и файлами с ЛАТИНИЦЕЙ в названии. По всем остальным элементам массива я получаю null, и соответственно фактически exec отрабатывает только на каталогах и файлах с латиницей

Если я проделываю тоже самое без применения ajax, и просто вывожу дамп массива на страницу, напрямую из контроллера

```
echo <pre>;
print_r($data);
echo </pre>;
```

То получаю следующее [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои exec команды выполняются на всех каталогах в папках, но в браузере я снова получаю иероглифы. (P/S полные пути в exec я оборачиваю в кавычки и слеши экранирую)

Я перепроверил кодировку всех своих файлов через notepad++, везде UTF-8 без BOM.
В файле http.conf я прописал в конце AddDefaultCharset utf-8.
В .htaccess в каталоге рядом с public директорией прописал AddCharset utf-8 .html .php .js .css .txt

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: дак у вас там и `execCommand` пустые в массиве, чего результаты то сравнивать? И почему вы пишите про папки, если работаете с файлами?

Comment: @teran, по флагу /T exec команда работает и со всеми файлами и папками во вложенных дирректориях. В том и проблема что execCommand при работе с данными по Ajax выполняется только для каталога с латиницей, и я не могу понять почему.

Comment: на картинке кстати у вас пишется `разрешения on folder` а в коде "разрешения на каталог", убедитесь, что у вас выложены корректные фрагменты кода, соответствующие получаемым результатам.

Comment: @teran, выполжены корректные фрагменты, я пытался понять что будет в ответе, если я буду менять пользовательский текст

Comment: Ну дак я вам пишу, что у вас там массив команд пуст, а вы смотрите не массив результатов. `execCommand` ведь содержит `null` по какой то причине? отсюда и `execSuccess` на тех же позициях содержит `null`, так?

Comment: В текущем коде, не ясно, как в командах могут получатся `null` элементы, поэтому и спросил, соответствует ли код картинкам

Comment: @teran - да, так

Comment: @teran, если я исключаю Ajax и работаю напрямую с контроллером через форму и post, то в массив ['execCommand'] полностью заполнен и ['execSuccess'] полностью отрабатывает

Comment: приложите нам тогда и содержимое `$paths` для обычного и аякс вызова перед циклом генерации команд (у вас там кавычка одна кстати лишняя двойная закрывающая). и в целом рекурсивно на директории то нельзя это сделать,а не каждому файлу?

Comment: у вас там в цикле в `paths` возвращаются вероятно не строки, а шляпа какая то (объект или еще чего), и конкатенация приводит к null. Надо смотреть, как строится список этих директорий/файлов. То есть проблема не в том коде. что прикреплен к вопросу.

Comment: @ teran, так пожалуй я еще раз соберусь  и пересоздам топик)